# ClosedXML - Issue with SOME colors when coping the cell fill

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, closedxml

#### Context

- Trying to create a small utility that copies excel files.
- Using c# (dotnet Framework 3.5) and closedXml (NuGet version: 0.71.1)
- Iterating all the cells in a predefined area one by one and coping the text and basic style properties.

#### Issue

The resulted copied file includes contents and styles but... only **SOME** colors are different from the source file:

(**left**: the original, **right**: the copy)
[image]

#### Code

```
private XLColor CopyColor(XLColor color, XLWorkbook workbook) {
    if (color.ColorType == XLColorType.Theme) {
        XLColor themeColor = GetThemeColor(color.ThemeColor, workbook);
        return XLColor.FromArgb(themeColor.Color.A, themeColor.Color.R, themeColor.Color.G, themeColor.Color.B);
    }

    if (color.Color.Name.ToLower().Equals("transparent")) {
        return XLColor.NoColor;
    }

    return XLColor.FromArgb(color.Color.A, color.Color.R, color.Color.G, color.Color.B);
}

private XLColor GetThemeColor(XLThemeColor themeColor, XLWorkbook workbook) {
    XLColor color;
    switch (themeColor) {
        case XLThemeColor.Accent1:
            color = workbook.Theme.Accent1;
            break;
        case XLThemeColor.Accent2:
            color = workbook.Theme.Accent2;
            break;
            ...
    }
    return XLColor.FromArgb(color.Color.A, color.Color.R, color.Color.G, color.Color.B);
}
```

#### Question

Why is this happening? Any insides on how to fix it?

---

**EDIT**

(edited the source code)

To answer the "*Why is this happening?*"

The issue occurs only with **ThemeColors** (side note: theme colors are specific to an excel file). The original excel file has this theme color palette:

[image]

... but when loading this exact file into a ClosedXml workbook object, the Theme colors do not match the ones defined in the file:

[image]

... which matches (or mis-matches) with this color palette:

[image]

It sounds like a bug where ClosedXml puts some default theme colors instead of the ones in the excel file.

---

Don't know if i hit a dead-end. The issue is still unresolved.

Comment: Looks like you're copying indexed colors between different Types that that use different palettes. Try copying their (A)RGB values instead.

Comment: That is a very old version of ClosedXML. I assume there's a reason you're still using .NET 3.5, but, if you can, try to use the latest version to see if it would solve the issue.

Comment: @schnitz77 i've followed your suggestion which helped, but it seems like the issue creeps elsewhere (you can see my edit)

Comment: @FrancoisBotha unfortunately .NET3.5 is a requirement and i picked the latest ClosedXml version which is compatible with .NET3.5.

Comment: @Mario You can try do a custom .NET 3.5 build. Get the code from Github and change the target framework. You might have to remove incompatible code.

Comment: As stated [ClosedXML on GitHub](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) in [issue Theme colors #98](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/98) ClosedXML has hardcoded scheme (similiar to office 2007-2010). Thus it might be useful to utilize named colors as explained [in their wiki](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Colors).